# Как сделать поочередное выполнение методов?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я, через `Lock` и `Condition` хотел сделать так, чтобы потоки выполнялись по очереди. Сначала 1-й, потом 2-й, потом опять 1-й, 2-й и так далее.
Я пытался сделать следующим образом и в целом как бы понятно почему это не работает, но не понятно как изменить это, чтобы работало.

```
class SomeClass {
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    static Condition condition  = lock.newCondition();
    static Condition condition1  = lock.newCondition();
    public void firstMethod() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            condition.await();
            System.out.println("firstMethod");
            System.out.println("firstMethod 1");
            System.out.println("firstMethod 2");
            System.out.println("secondMethod 3");
            condition1.signal();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void secondMethod() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            System.err.println("secondMethod");
            System.err.println("secondMethod 1");
            System.err.println("secondMethod 2");
            System.err.println("secondMethod 3");
            condition.signal();
            condition1.await();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public class LockExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SomeClass sm = new SomeClass();
        Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
           try {
               sm.firstMethod();
           } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        });

        Thread th2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                sm.secondMethod();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        th.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы ждать второй потек, после прохода первого. Не знаю, для чего вам это, но из-за некоторой не определенности работы потоков, придется следить, кто выполняет код. И если это поток один, ставить метку, что этот поток отработал. В таком случае запускать второй, когда он отработает, снова менять метку, что второй поток отработал. Нужно именно уникальные метки, а не true false. Но лучше бы пересмотреть логику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще один способ, но встроенными инструментами java:

```
class SomeClass2 {
    static boolean run = true;
    public void firstMethod() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (!run) {
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.println("first");
                run = false;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public void secondMethod() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (run) {
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.println("second");
                run = true;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть несколько проблем.

Первая, это опечатка в `firstMethod`. Он выдает себя за второй поток тут:

```
System.out.println("firstMethod 2");
System.out.println("secondMethod 3");
```

Следующая проблема - это использования двух разных потоков вывода `System.out` и `System.err`. В зависимости от того, как вы запускаете вашу программу, где-то будет происходить слияние этих потоков вывода в один. Это может делать IDE если вывод идет в одну консоль, или если запускаете из терминала, то терминал. При этом там может быть буферизация и вывод в финальное место (после слияния) будет не в том порядке, в котором потоки выполнения писали в потоки вывода.

Чтоб устранить эту проблему, нужно использовать один поток вывода для обоих потоков выполнения.

И наконец, собственно проблема с многопоточностью и использованием `Condition`. Эта реализация не работает, потому что возможна такая последовательность исполнения:

1. оба потока заходят в цикл
2. `secondMethod` захватывает лок
3. `secondMethod` пишет консоль
4. `secondMethod` посылает сигнал `condition.signal()`

Проблема в том, что `firstMethod` в это время не ждал в методе `condition.await` и сигнал от второго потока будет пропущен. Теперь два потока будут вечно ждать: `firstMethod` на `condition.wait`, а `secondMethod` на `condition1.wait` и у нас получился deadlock.

Решить это можно так, чтоб поток не продолжал выполнение, пока второй не дойдет до определенной точки. Это можно сделать с помощью `CyclicBarrier`:

```
class SomeClass {
    static CyclicBarrier secondCanRun = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    static CyclicBarrier firstCanRun = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    public void firstMethod() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        while (true) {
            firstCanRun.await();
            System.out.println("firstMethod");
            System.out.println("firstMethod 1");
            System.out.println("firstMethod 2");
            System.out.println("firstMethod 3");
            secondCanRun.await();
        }
    }

    public void secondMethod() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        firstCanRun.await();
        while (true) {
            secondCanRun.await();
            System.out.println("secondMethod");
            System.out.println("secondMethod 1");
            System.out.println("secondMethod 2");
            System.out.println("secondMethod 3");
            firstCanRun.await();
        }
    }
}
```

Тут в точках `firstCanRun.await()` и `secondCanRun.await()` потоки будут ждать друг друга.